# How to determine chart type inside 'chart.js' pluginservice

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to find out chart type if i use Chart.pluginService.register I have a loop that call out chart function which is common for all chart and I am unable to populate the line chart. therefore i need to find out its type.
mentioned below is my code:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeDraw: function (chart) {

    if (chart.config.type !== "donught")
```

my loop which calls this service

```
for (var i=1; i<8;i++)
{
if (i == 7) 
        {
           var type1 = 'line'}
           else {var type1 = 'doughnut'}

new Chart(document.getElementById('doughnut-chart'+i), {

    type: type1,
    data: datas[i],
    options: option[i]

});

}
```

I tried 'chart.config.type' which I dont think is valid. How to find out the chart type inside 'Chart.pluginService.register'

Comment: Not sure if this is any related to your problem but in `chart.config.type !== "donught"`, it should be `"doughnut"`

Comment: thanks uminder actually you are correct. and I invested my time making adjustment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#global-plugins) you need to use `Chart.plugins.register`, not `Chart.pluginService.register`. Otherwise your code seems to work.

Here's a working example:

```js
Chart.plugins.register({
  beforeDraw: function(chart) {
    console.log(chart.config.type)
  }
});

new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "doughnut"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```